# Pinescript - realtime candle call from indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to call an alert in real-time mode.
Unfortunately, despite locking the instructions, several alerts are triggered consecutively.

Therefore, when the indicator outputs a long, the indicator's instruction switches between long and short several times in real-time mode until the candle ends.

So far I haven't managed to allow just one short in the real-time candle if the last trend was long. does anyone have an idea to solve this?

The alert instruction alert.freq_once_per_bar also does not work in real-time mode. despite what is stated in the alert statement.
I haven't figured out why yet. Therefore, it would be interesting to be able to evaluate only one instruction of the indicator in real-time mode when setting up the candle. And exactly the one that should follow the last trade direction.

Here is the indicator:

```
//@version=5
strategy("Test 100 - On-balance volume 2fach Indikator", process_orders_on_close=true, max_bars_back = 4000, overlay=true, max_lines_count=500, max_labels_count=500, calc_on_every_tick=tue)

bool its_long = na
bool its_short = na
varip int sperr_long = 1
varip int sperr_short = 1

period=input(7,"Period")
shift=input(1,"Shift")
exp=input(false,"Exponential moving average")
max=exp?ta.ema(high[shift],period):ta.sma(high[shift],period)
min=exp?ta.ema(low[shift],period):ta.sma(low[shift],period)
pos=close>max?-1:close<min?1:0
pos:=pos==0?nz(pos[1]):pos
hilo=pos==1?max:min
plotbar(hilo,hilo,hilo,hilo,color=pos==1?color.red:color.green)


if pos == -1 and sperr_long == 1
    its_long := true
    sperr_long := sperr_long + 1
    sperr_short := 1 

if pos == 1 and sperr_short == 1
    its_short := true
    sperr_short := sperr_short + 1
    sperr_long := 1 


plotshape(its_long == true,  style=shape.labelup,   location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
plotshape(its_short == true, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.small)

ind_2_long := its_long == true
ind_2_short := its_short == true
```

Comment: I tried that. If I lock long and short together then no more trades will be executed. It depends on whether I work with varip. because in real time a var is held and not reset. Problem still remains. How can I manage the different states in a realtime candle?